# Website or browser plugin to see email as chats

Tags: email, chat

The following image shows the way Gmail represents a long thread of emails between two persons with the same object. You can see the headers and not the text of the single emails.

[image: Gmail interface, showing list of emails]

This kind of emails are functionally identical to a chat. There is no need for an object, there is no need for an header, just seeing the author and the text of the emails would be enough. It's just me and another person. Every message consist of few lines. And there are tons of messages. Google Wave was doing something good in this sense.

Can I visualize this thread of emails as if they were messages in a Facebook Chat

> Me: blablabla
>   Him: dsfsdfjsdklfjsdlf
>   Me: dfasfjklsdjflkdjsf
>   Him: fhsdjkfhsdf

without any header?

Is there any tool/plugin to do something similar?

Comment: So it must be a webmail client or a browser plugin (that works especially with Gmail’s web interface?), but not a stand-alone email client?

Comment: @unor: a standalone client would be better than nothing.. but a webapp like gmail or a plugin for chrome / firefox would be the best

Answer (score 1):

I've found a Chrome Plugins which satisfy my request. The name is Streak (https://www.streak.com/)

The feature can be accessed from this menu. The tool seems pretty mature while I'm writing (end of 2015), but in my personal preference this should be the preferred way of showing thread of mails.

It also allows for some collaborative tools.

[image]